# Pareto distribution rules out stable distribution?

Tags: distributions, estimation, fitting, nonparametric, pareto-distribution

In the following paper http://fic.wharton.upenn.edu/fic/papers/99/9914.pdf on catastrophic damage, I read a sentence the puzzled me (p. 23):

> For the hurricane data the Pareto gives the heaviest tail estimates. In fact the MLE estimates of the Pareto parameters ($\lambda=177.64$, $\alpha=0.797$) indicate that the distribution is *not stable* and moments are undefined.

Why does this indicate that the distribution is not stable? I don't see the reason for such a conclusion - the stable distribution has Pareto-like tails (asymptotically). Does he mean "not of stable Paretian law"? What could have been the author's reason for this statement? There can be plenty of reasons to dismiss a stable dist., but the one stated?

Comment: Can you give more context? I'm as confused as you are from the isolated statement you pasted.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The authors then turn to other distributions. So I guess they just mean that this specific distribution doesn't fit very well.

Comment: The moments (i.e. the mean $E(X)$) of a Pareto distribution is only defined for $\alpha > 1$. Since the MLE is $\hat\alpha = 0.797$, the mean, variance etc of the distribution is $\infty$, or rather, undefined.